# knowing about mongodb collections

Tags: python, mongodb

I found something or I don't know about mongodb is a array of collectsions. I want to implement the dynamic collections in mongodb. I came from python and I created dynamic classes. I played two queries and it gave same thing.

```
> db['shopping_cart'].find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5438b8afa4bc2874f342f36c"), "items" : [ ], "coupon_codes_used" : [ ], "owner" : 2062 }
```

and

```
> db.shopping_cart.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5438b8afa4bc2874f342f36c"), "items" : [ ], "coupon_codes_used" : [ ], "owner" : 2062 }
```

What is the difference between those queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both valid syntax.

typically you would use

```
db.shopping_cart.find()
```

however, if your collection name has any characters that mongo doesn't accept in a collection name, you can use the alternative syntax instead.

```
db["shopping_cart"].find()
```

**Example**

If your collection was named "shopping-cart" (hyphen instead of underscore). Mongo would not accept this as a collection name. `db.shopping-cart.insert({"name":"value"})` would return an error. In this situation, you would be required to use `db['shopping-cart'].insert({"name":"value"})` if you insist on using "shopping-cart" as your collection name.

Source: [Getting Started with the mongo Shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/)